# Can't find error in my c code

Tags: c

can't find an error please help, this is a C code to find minimum number of possible quadrangles on co-ordinate plane

```
#include <stdio.h>

int quadrangle(int *,int);
int min(int,int);

int main(){

int t,i,j,n,p[n][n];
printf("\nEnter the number of test cases");
scanf("%d",&t);
for(i=0;i<t;i++){
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(j=0;j<n;j++){
        scanf("%d %d",&p[j][0],&p[j][1]);
    }
    printf("%d",quadrangle(&p[0][0],n));
}
return 0;
}

int quadrangle(int *p,int len){
int f=0,s=0,t=0,fo=0,i;
for(i=0;i<len;i++){
    if(*(p+i*len)>0&&*(p+i*len+1)>0)
        f++;
    if(*(p+i*len)>0&&*(p+i*len+1)<0)
        s++;
    if(*(p+i*len)<0&&*(p+i*len+1)<0)
        t++;
    if(*(p+i*len)<0&&*(p+i*len+1)>0)
        fo++;
}
return min(min(f,s),min(t,fo));
}

int min(int a,int b){
if(a>b) return b;
else return a;}
```

I tested it on codeblocks software it is compiling okay but ends abruptly when I execute it . The control doesn't even enter main() .

Answer (score 1):

`n` is uninitialized and you create an array of size `n` (guess what's the value of `n`) here:

```
int t,i,j,n,p[n][n];
```

Declare the array *after* `n` gets initialized, i.e, change

```
int t,i,j,n,p[n][n];
```

to

```
int t,i,j,n;
```

and add

```
int p[n][n];
```

after

```
scanf("%d",&n);
```